# How to set transparency of a .png image file in opengl ES?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to position an image(.png) in my window using OpenGL ES...I have done that but I want to set the transparency of that image.

Comment: things you should check: the image is loaded using `GL_RGBA` or equivalent and that the fragment shader blends the colors taking the alpha channel into account.

Comment: I have done some coding and it removes the background as I needed but not perfectly , it is because of the color code value, But It also removes the color inside the image rather than the background...how can I avoid that..

Comment: did you check that the alpha is set to opaque in those portions of the image?